# Python - Is isolation via generic try blocks bad?

Tags: python, exception

Say I have some complex code where I have nested try blocks with the generic `except Exception, e` because I need to isolate certain (sometimes unknown) failures from causing a long running program to halt.

Those failures are usually not important enough to halt the program, but I want to catch them so I can log them as errors and so fourth.  The problem comes with trying to reraise certain exceptions that SHOULD cause the program to fail, and also trying to implement unit tests on the sections of code under these generic try/except blocks.  Things like "assertRaises" don't really work since any failure is being caught.

Is there a better way to isolate parts of a Python program from causing the entire program to halt without using such generic try/except blocks?  I also want to try to stay away from threads/multiprocessing/subprocess if possible.

Comment: Do you know what specific class of errors should be logged and ignored, or what class should force death? If you want to only log errors from your application, maybe subclass all your custom errors from one base, then catch the base. If only a few errors should force a quit, catch those specifically. A `try` block can have multiple `except` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small methods which do not use try...catch, but are used in larger methods/functions which wrap them in try...catch is the usual solution.
This would easily allow tests to check the exceptions.